# Getting Years Of Service

Tags: ms-access

I have the following code:

```
SELECT O896IA_VEMPPRSA.REG_NR, O896IA_VEMPPRSA.DIS_NR, O896IA_VEMPPRSA.CTR_NR, O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR, O867IA_VPJOBCO.JOB_CLS_CD, O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_RHR_DT
FROM O896IA_VEMPPRSA INNER JOIN O867IA_VPJOBCO ON O896IA_VEMPPRSA.JOB_CLS_CD = O867IA_VPJOBCO.JOB_CLS_CD
WHERE (((O867IA_VPJOBCO.JOB_GRP_CD)="61") AND ((O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_EMT_STS_CD)<>"T"))
GROUP BY O896IA_VEMPPRSA.REG_NR, O896IA_VEMPPRSA.DIS_NR, O896IA_VEMPPRSA.CTR_NR, O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR, O867IA_VPJOBCO.JOB_CLS_CD, O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_RHR_DT;
```

EMP_RHR_DT is a Date/Time data type, I need a code that subtracts whatever data it is being access by the EMP_RHR_DT and divides by 365 so I can get the YOS. I have Used

```
YOS: Int((Date()-[EMP_RHR_DT])/365)
```

But this brings up the error : ODBC CALL FAILED: Inconsistent datatypes: Expected CHAR got DATE (932)

Comment: Where did you put YOS in the original query?

Comment: Could I suggest using `DateDiff()`?  http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php